# How to find the wikidata ID of a DBpedia concept?

Tags: uses-of-open-data, research, wikidata, rdf, dbpedia

I have a set of DBpedia concepts and would like to get the corresponding wikidata IDs of them.

For example, consider word2vec. The wikidata ID of word2vec is `wd:Q22673982`.

Currently, I have the following two questions.

- Are all DBpedia concepts associated with its relevent wikidata ID?
- How to get the wikidata ID associated with DBpedia using sparql?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 3):

```
Q1: Are all DBpedia concepts associated with its relevent wikidata ID?
```

Those kind of links are usually generated by the people on either side into the direction of the other side. Since it is sometimes very hard to automatically detect links, it is very unlikely that a link between all concepts, properties or entities exist. If you are interested in the linking process, you could check out some research papers which describe how those graph databases generated links to external graphs: 
https://scholar.google.de/scholar?q=wikidata+dbpedia+linking

```
Q2: How to get the wikidata ID associated with DBpedia using sparql?
```

By using the SPARQL endpoint of dbpedia: http://dbpedia.org/sparql. You have to first select all `owl:sameAs` results and then filter them, so you only end up with your Wikidata URI.

Example query:

```
SELECT distinct ?wikidata_concept

WHERE {dbr:Word2vec owl:sameAs ?wikidata_concept

      FILTER(regex(str(?wikidata_concept), "www.wikidata.org" ) )
}

LIMIT 100
```